# Redirect from one admin view to another model view in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to find a way of opening different admin view on column selection.

My very simplified models are following:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_lenght=200)

class modelB(models.Model):
     modelsA = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modelBs')
     value = models.IntegerField()
```

And in admin I have following view:

```
class modelA_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_view = ('__str__', 'total_modelBs')

     def total_modelBs(self, obj):
         try:
              total = obj.modelBs.all().count()
         except modelB.DoesNotExist:
              total = 0
      return total
```

What I'd like to get is be able to open `modelB` Admin view with values filtered for those that have given `modelA` id once I click on value `total_modelBs`.

Any idea, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out solution has been rather simple. Basically something like this should work:

```
class modelA_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_view = ('__str__', 'total_modelBs')

     def total_modelBs(self, obj):
         try:
              total = obj.modelBs.all().count()
         except modelB.DoesNotExist:
              total = 0
         link = reverse("admin:MyApp_modelb_changelist")
         return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>',mark_safe(link), total)
      total_modelBs.short_description = 'modelBs total'
```

I have showed here how to set redirect for changelist, all of the options can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).